# angular show/hide div outside ng view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

trying to hide/show div outside ng-view but can not access it.

main controller

```
var vm = this;
vm.showMyDiv = false;
```

html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ManinCtrl as main">
    <div ng-show="vm.showMyDiv">
      my test div
    </div>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
<body>
```

ng-view controller

```
var vm = this;
vm.hideLoader = true;
```

how can I access it, I tried with $scope but it does not work

Comment: Your first and second controller are the parent and the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the controller like this `ng-controller="ManinCtrl as main"` so you need to prefix the properties with `main` and not `vm`

```
<div ng-show="main.showMyDiv">
```

Working example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var main = this;
  main.showMe = false;
  main.toggleShow = function() {
    main.showMe = !main.showMe;
  };
}).controller('ctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.exampleText = "I'm inner text in the controller :)";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <div ng-show="main.showMe">HELLO!!</div>
  
  <hr>
  
  <div ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <div ng-bind="vm.exampleText"></div>
    <button ng-click="main.toggleShow()">Click Here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but how can change the div visibility from nested controller that handles the view ?

Comment: @user1751287 I added a working example of how it should be done. Hope it will help you better understand my answer

Comment: I dont know why but can not make it work and I see that your example works. I dont see errors but nothing happens

Comment: my nested controller is defined within routes, controller: 'nestedCtrl', controllerAs: 'vm'

Comment: OK, but since you say that you have a parent controller - So you don't need to call `vm.<property>` but to the main controller

Comment: will use jqLite options to handle it, thanks will mark your answer as correct as it works